# Visual Studio 2012 : generating debug info in release mode

Tags: visual-studio

I want to generate callstacks with stackWalker, so i need to generate debug infos in release mode.
But, in release mode, when the program crash somewhere or stop at a breakpoint, then it takes ages for VS to show the line in the editor : sometimes it takes 1 minute, sometimes more than 5 minutes, sometimes i have to kill VS process ...

Is there any options to work around that ?
Regards

Comment: Can you detail your environment.  Asp.net, console app, WinForms, etc.  Also add OS and amount of RAM.

Comment: - windows8 / 2gigs ram

- /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

- i create a window with SDL2.0 -> SDL_CreateWindow()

Comment: I think your real problem is the amount of ram you have.  2gb isn't very much ram with any version of windows from Windows 7 onward.  In my experience, VS is a memory hog.   I'm using VS2015 and it normally starts out with 1gb of ram used.  If you can, upgrade to at least 4gb, 8gb would be better

Comment: humm i desactivated all additional debug extensions i installed for God knows what reason, and it seems fine now.

Comment: Good point about extensions, I'd forgot about that